# Ensuring correct order when collecting results from multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing script which loops over a dictionary like so:

```
jobs = []
for key, val in datadict.items():
    jobs.append(pool.apply_async(worker, (val))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

`jobs` is then a list of result objects, (where calling `get()` will give a list of data)

I want to format the results so that they are a dictionary with the same keys and order as the input dictionary.

I thought to simply do this after all jobs had completed:

```
result = {key: jobs[key].get() for key, val in datadict}
```

Which works because the keys in `datadict` are integers (so can be used to index the jobs list). 
But then it occurred to me that perhaps the resultant jobs list is not necessarily in the same order (as it is created) - is this true? (I would expect the order could become muddled as one process might finish quicker than another etc)

So I decided to pass the `key` of `datadict` into the worker function and simply return it again with the result as a tuple. So that calling `jobs[index].get()` would return a tuple where the first value is the key (which has just passed through the function) and the second value is the actual result

I can then create a dictionary like so:

```
result = dict([job.get() for job in jobs])
```

so the final script is:

```
def worker(val, key):        
    res = "Do something to val"
    return (key, res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    jobs = []
    for key, val in datadict.items():
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(worker, (val, key))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    result = dict([job.get() for job in jobs])
```

But is this the best method of doing this? There are a couple of points that bug me:

1. So far, the resulting order of the `jobs` list has matched the input order
2. It seems a bit silly to pass a value 'through' a function (i.e. doing nothing with it)

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly sort the `datadict` dictionary keys, and iterate that.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(val):
    res = "Do something to val {}".format(val)
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    datadict = {1: 'val1', 2: 'val2', 0: 'val0'}
    jobs = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for key in sorted(datadict): # <------------
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(worker, (datadict[key],)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    result = [job.get() for job in jobs]
    print(result)
    # ['Do something to val 0', 'Do something to val 1', 'Do something to val 2']
```

BTW, if `worker` accepts only one parameter, you can use [`Pool.map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    datadict = {1: 'val1', 2: 'val2', 0: 'val0'}
    jobs = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = pool.map(worker, sorted(datadict)) # <---
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` container doesn't guarantee any particular ordering. If you want to keep things ordered you either need to store the results in a `list`:

```
result = [job.get() for job in jobs]
```

or you can use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) which maintains insertion order:

```
result = OrderedDict([job.key, job.get() for job in jobs])
```

Second solution requires a way to obtain a key from a job.

**Update:**:

If order is given by key then you can just sort the results by this attribute (job needs to know its key):

```
results = [job.get() for job in jobs]
results = sorted(results, key=attrgetter('key'))
```

Or if you need a `dict`:

```
results = [job.get() for job in jobs]
results = OrderedDict([job.key, job for job in sorted(results, key=attrgetter('key'))])
```

Comment: The order is given by the key... Perhaps 'order' is the wrong word to use. I need the correct result to be assigned to the correct key.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs may complete out of order, but that does not change the order of your `jobs` list. However, you populate `jobs` by looping over `datadict.items()`; that puts them in arbitrary order because dictionaries do not maintain order.

Putting the keys in `jobs` would be one way to do what you want:

```
jobs = []
for key, val in datadict.items():
    jobs.append((key, pool.apply_async(worker, (val,)))

pool.close()
pool.join()

result = {key: job.get() for key, job in jobs}
```

Comment: how does this work? Say my dictionary has two items in it, if the 2nd item completes first, will this not get appended to the jobs list before the first item (and therefore be in the wrong place)?

Comment: You append the result objects to `jobs` yourself in the `for` loop. Nothing rearranges them after. Calling `get` on a result object waits for the actual result to arrive, but does not change the order of the list.